# I'm having trouble selectiong an element using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, element

I want to read out the text in this html element using selenium with python. I just can't find a way to find or select it without using the text (i don't want that because its content changes)

```
<div font-size="14px" color="text" class="sc-gtsrHT jFEWVt">0.101 ONE</div>
```

Do you have an idea how i could select it? The conventional ways listed in the documentation seem to not work for me. To be honest i'm not very good with html what doesn't make things any easier.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this class `sc-gtsrHT jFEWVt` also gets changed often  ?

Comment: up till now it doesn't seem like the class changes but it would be nice to have a solution for that aswell because i stumble over a lot of elements I can't find a unique identifier to.

Comment: For that I need to see outer HTML, if you can share page url that'd be great !

Comment: the url is [pancakeswap](https://pancakeswap.finance/swap) .
you'd have to put in 2 different tokens and wait a second. The specific element I'm looking for is the value from the then shown "Liquidity Provider Fee"

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
element = browser.find_element_by_class_name('sc-gtsrHT jFEWVt').text
```

Or use a loop if you have several elements :

```
elements = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('sc-gtsrHT jFEWVt')
for e in elements:
    print(e.text)
```

Comment: Thank you. That seemed to work. I just had to code is as css selector:

`
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.sc-gtsrHT.jFEWVt')
            for e in elements:
                print(e.text)
`

Answer (score 0):

```
print(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='sc-gtsrHT jFEWVt']").text)
```

You could simply grab it by class name. It's 2 class names so it would be like so. by_class_name only uses one.

If the class name isn't dynamic otherwise you'd have to right click and copy the xpath or find a unique identiftier.

Comment: How do i get unique identifier? The xpath is variable it seems and the other values are not unique inside the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Find by XPath as long as font size and color attribute are consistent. Be like,

```
//div[@font-size='14px' and @color='text' and starts-with(@class,'sc-')]
```

I guess the class name is random?

Comment: The class name seems to be consistent but there are other elements having the exact same specifications, what causes the programm to read the first of them.